# Socket.io get the namespace a socket belongs to

Tags: javascript, websocket, socket.io

Is there a way to get a sockets namespace? I've tried various things but cannot get it to work. Given a socket object I would like to be able to know what namespace it belongs to. Thank you very much.

for example

```
nsp = io.of('/' + venue_code).on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.namespace = nsp
    if (typeof servers[nsp.name] == 'undefined') {
        servers[nsp.name] = socket.id
        winston.debug("Server " + socket.id + " connected to " + nsp.name)
        socket.room = "servers"
        socket.join(socket.room)
    } else {
        socket.room = "clients"
        socket.join(socket.room)
        winston.debug("Client " + socket.id + " connected to " + nsp.name)
    }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is just `socket.nsp`, which gives the entire `Namespace` object. Use `socket.nsp.name` to get the actual name.

```
nsp = io.of('/' + venue_code).on('connection', function(socket) {
    winston.debug(socket.nsp)
}
```

Note that if you attach this same handler to the root namespace, you'll get the root namespace -- those middlewares are run *before* the correct namespace is attached.

Comment: This doesn't work in `io.on('connection', ...)` -- it thinks I'm connecting to `/`, not `/actual-nsp`.